# Explode list of dictionaries into additional columns in Spark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I currently have a UDF that takes a column of xml strings and parses it into lists of dictionaries. I then want to explode that list of dictionaries column out into additional columns based on the key-value pairs.

Input looks like this:

```
   id  type  length  parsed    
0  1   A     144     [{'key1':'value1'},{'key1':'value2', 'key2':'value3'},...]
1  1   B     20      [{'key1':'value4'},{'key2':'value5'},...]
2  4   A     54      [{'key3':'value6'},...]
```

And I want the output to look like this:

```
   id  type  length  key1             key2     key3
0  1   A     144     [value1,value2]  value3
1  1   B     20      value4           value5
2  4   A     54                                value6
```

I have been able to do this in Pandas like so:

```
s = data['parsed xml'].explode()
df_join = (pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), index = s.index)
             .stack()
             .groupby(level=[0,1])
             .agg(list)
             .apply(lambda x: x[0] if len(x)==1 else x)
             .unstack(fill_value='')
          )
t = data.join(df_join, lsuffix = '_x', rsuffix = '_y')
```

The issue is I am having trouble converting this Pandas code in Spark (won't have Pandas available to me) that would give me the same result.

The Spark I will have available is 1.6.0.

Comment: can you include the spark version?

Comment: use `explode` function then group by and in agg `collect_list`

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala Spark 1.6.0

Comment: @chlebek Could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `explode` twice - once to explode the array and once to explode the map elements of the array. Thereafter, you can use `pivot` with a `collect_list` aggregation.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode,collect_list
#explode array
df_1 = df.withColumn('exploded_arr',explode('parsed')) 
#explode maps of array elements
df_2 = df_1.select(*df_1.columns,explode('exploded_arr')) #the default column names returned after exploding a map are `key`,`value`. change them as needed
#pivot with aggregation
df_2.groupBy("id","length","type").pivot("key").agg(collect_list("value")).show()
```

Comment: Thank you. I get the error though `ImportError: cannot import name 'pivot'`

Comment: you don't need to import it..corrected the function imports.

Comment: Thanks. This gives me a `IllegalArgumentException: 'Unsupported class file major version 55'` error but that is something different I believe. Do you mind showing what the output could look like?

Comment: How can you use `collect_list` in Spark 1.6?

Comment: look at the [`documentation`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list)

Comment: I tried your code in Spark 1.6/Python 2.6.6 and it gives me `undefined function collect_list`

Comment: you should import the function to use it .. edited my answer.