# Explode list of dictionaries in PySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

This is a follow up to [Explode list of dictionaries into additional columns in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62646542/explode-list-of-dictionaries-into-additional-columns-in-spark/62647472#62647472).

Input looks like this:

```
   id  type  length  parsed    
0  1   A     144     [{'key1':'value1'},{'key1':'value2', 'key2':'value3'},...]
1  1   B     20      [{'key1':'value4'},{'key2':'value5'}, {'key3':'value6'},...]
2  4   A     54      [{'key3':'value7'},...]
```

I want one key (say `key1`) to expand into multiple rows if there are multiple dictionaries with `key1` in a particular row (i.e. row 0). But I only want that for `key1` -- all other ones with multiples should be in a list.  I want the output to look like this:

```
   id  type  length  key1             key2     key3
0  1   A     144     value1           value3
1  1   A     144     value2           value3
1  1   B     20      value4           value5
2  4   A     54                                [value6,value7]
```

This was what I got from the previous answer but I don't know if it would work with the above case:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
#explode array
df_1 = df.withColumn('exploded_arr',explode('parsed')) 
#explode maps of array elements
df_2 = df_1.select(*df_1.columns,explode('exploded_arr')) #the default column names returned after exploding a map are `key`,`value`. change them as needed
#pivot with aggregation
df_2.groupBy("id","length","type").pivot("key").agg(collect_list("value")).show()
```

Is this a simple fix?